# Convert the MultiValueMap returned by FormHttpMessageConverter into Domain Object

Tags: java, spring, spring-restcontroller

I am posting a `x-www-formurlencoded` string to my spring rest application and it automatically converts it into the default `MultiValueMap<String, Object>` object and passes it in as a parameter like so:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, 
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE, 
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
@ResponseBody
public User save(@Valid @RequestBody final MultiValueMap<String, Object>  
userMultiValueMap) {

...

}
```

How do I go about customizing my default handlers, so that a specific domain object (eg. say `User` object) is automatically mapped and can be passed in as a parameter instead. This would look like the automatic binding you get with a plain `application/json` post with the following:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, 
    consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
@ResponseBody
public User save(@Valid @RequestBody final User user) {

...

}
```

`User` object is mapped and created from the `application/json` request body post. How can I configure my `HttpMessageConverter` handling to achieve something similar with `x-www-formurlencoded` and get a domain object , and not a `MultiValueMap` that is provided with the default handling in `FormHttpMessageConverter`.

Answer (score -1):

you just need to add MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter to your converters and Spring should be able to do what you want automatically.

you also need to have jackson library on classpath, and your User must be a java bean.

if you want form data instead json you just need FormHttpMessageConverter. Also remove consumes=... json part from the method annotation.

Comment: They don't want JSON. They want form data.